# Custom Joomla authorization

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

The situation is quite complicated and why do I need it - do not ask - boss want!

So, immediately after the default authorization i need to run the custom module, which will have an additional test for authorization in another database and depending on its result i need to decide authorize user or not.

Are there any suggestions except for source corrections?

Comment: Is this additional authorization for the backend admin panel?

Comment: @Lodder the point is that the joomla is used only for template... The main project(script) has his own authorization. So after joomla authorization i need to check data secont time and only after that let user in.

Comment: So you're not using the Joomla login system, you're using your own I assume. I will advise you to tell your boss that the Joomla login system is very secure and uses SALT aswell as md5. see this link for more details regarding the encryption: stackoverflow.com/questions/10428126/joomla-password-encryption. If your boss really doesn't want to stick with Joomla only, then you can redirect the user to your second authorization page once they are logged in

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Joomla's built-in 'Login Menu', you can set 'Login Redirect' parameter to another page and if you are using Joomla's native login module, you can set redirect parameter to any page of your site that you want.

In your case I would recommend to create a simple component (not a module) that authorizes your user for second time, and redirects them again to any other page that you want (if second login was successful) or kick the user (if second login was unsuccessful). If you do that, you'll be able to create a menu for your component and redirect your login panel (either it's a menu or a simple login module) to your component's menu.

Creating components for Joomla is not a big deal if you have a little of knowledge in php programming and there are some tools that may speed up creating your component, like this one: http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/

Comment: yes, I'm trying to create a component. The main problem - how to make the components work right after basic authorization?

Comment: What do you mean 'work'? Are you talking about your second authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make an authentication plugin and use that rather than the core joomla one?

This is for 1.5 but the principles are the same now.
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you use will check the password you want in the table you want.  Look at the LDAP as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Are the Joomla login credentials for a user the same as the other system that you are using? If so, then you can create a plugin that passes those credentials to your other system on a successful Joomla login event.

If not, then it gets a little tricky. Either your users will have to provide both sets of credentials, once for Joomla that then redirects to your other system for the second login, or you will have to extend your user accounts so you can associate the second set of credentials to a user. You can then use a plugin to pass the related credentials to your secondary system after a successful Joomla login event.